# How to turn off request body logging in elastic-apm

Tags: python, fastapi, elastic-apm

I am using **elastic-apm** middleware with **FastApi**. During serving each request my application is making several data-heavy request to external resources. My current setup is the following:

```
app = FastAPI(
    title="My API", description="Hello from my API!"
)

apm = make_apm_client(
    {
        "SERVICE_NAME": "MyService",
        "SERVER_URL": CONFIG["elastic_apm"]["server_url"],
        "SECRET_TOKEN": CONFIG["elastic_apm"]["token"],
    }
)

app.add_middleware(ElasticAPM, client=apm)
```

So, under high load my application sends a lot of unnecessary data to elastic apm (**I really don't need to save the body of each request**). Is there any way I could **turn off logging body and other request details**, and send to apm **only time and destination** of each particular request my app has made?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use the [`capture_body` config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/configuration.html#config-capture-body) to tweak this behavior. Typically you would set this to `off` or `errors` so you don't waste a lot of resources saving the request body for successful transactions.

However, the default should be `off`, which does not capture the body. Are you seeing request bodies being captured, or are they showing up as `[REDACTED]`?

You can also use [`capture_headers`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/configuration.html#config-capture-headers) to turn off header capture and set [`span_stack_trace_min_duration`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/configuration.html#config-span-stack-trace-min-duration) to `-1ms` to disable stack track capturing.

As far as the rest of the information goes, we don't have an easy way to turn off everything except the timing information. You could write a [processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/sanitizing-data.html) to drop all the extra data, for example. But I should note that elasticsearch is very efficient storing data that is similar across transactions, so I don't think you need to worry about dropping all of this extra data.